# How can I gain read/write access to a restricted android directory(say /data/data/<pkg_name>/)?

Tags: android, permissions, root, android-permissions, runtime.exec

I am not getting any resources to learn. I was able to ask for root permission (using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") command). But even after that, I am not getting read/write access to those files. I am a beginner. So, please don't mind if the question was a stupid one. I think you know what I am trying to do...

Comment: look at this answer will help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52213869/9093630

Comment: This is not what I want. I just want, say, copy a file from anywhere to /data/data/ folder, which requires the phone to be rooted, I know, but I am seeking for implementation.